# What does this mean in a jasmine test: Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working to get some Typescript classes tested with Jasmine. I've created some classes that compose with each other via module declarations:

```
module xxx.DeviceData {
    export class ConsoleListener extends DataListener {
        constructor() {
            super("ConsoleListener");
        }

        addData(data: string) {
            console.log(this.title + ": " + data);
        }

        clear() {
            console.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm composing the Jasmine tests together the same way:

```
module xxx.DeviceData {
 describe('ConsoleListener test', function () {
     var consoleListener,
         consoleListenerObj;

     beforeEach(() => {
         consoleListener = jasmine.createSpy("consoleListener");

         consoleListenerObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('consoleListenerObj', ['onSuccess', 'onFailure', 'addData', 'clear']);
         consoleListenerObj.onSuccess();
         consoleListenerObj.onFailure();
         consoleListenerObj.addData();
         consoleListenerObj.clear();
     });

     it('test#1 columnDefinition defined', function () {
         let consoleListener = new ConsoleListener();

         expect(consoleListener).not.toBeNull();
     });

     it('test#2 call onSuccess', function () {
         expect(consoleListenerObj.onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });

     it('test#3 call onFailure', function () {
         expect(consoleListenerObj.onFailure).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });

     it('test#4 call addData', function () {
         expect(consoleListenerObj.addData('123'));
     });

     it('test#5 call clear', function () {
         expect(consoleListenerObj.clear());
     });
 });
}
```

This all transpiles perfectly. When I try to execute the test, I receive this error

Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined   at Scripts/DeviceData/ConsoleListener.js:5:27

Something is going wrong on line 5 of the transpiled JS, right? Here is that:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var xxx;
(function (xxx) {
    var DeviceData;
    (function (DeviceData) {
        var ConsoleListener = (function (_super) {
            __extends(ConsoleListener, _super);
            function ConsoleListener() {
                return _super.call(this, "ConsoleListener") || this;
            }
            ConsoleListener.prototype.addData = function (data) {
                console.log(this.title + ": " + data);
            };
            ConsoleListener.prototype.clear = function () {
                console.clear();
            };
            return ConsoleListener;
        }(DeviceData.DataListener));
        DeviceData.ConsoleListener = ConsoleListener;
    })(DeviceData = xxx.DeviceData || (xxx.DeviceData = {}));
})(xxx|| (xxx= {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=ConsoleListener.js.map
```

And sure enough, line 5 seems to be talking about objects and prototypes.

I've tried different ways to get the modules to talk to each other, but this module approach is the only one I can get to work consistently. Is there something missing from the karma / jasmine context that needs to be passed here?

Here is my karma.config:

```
    module.exports = function (config) {
        config.set({

            frameworks: ["jasmine","karma-typescript"],

            preprocessors: {
                "Scripts/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
            },

            files: [
                'Scripts/DeviceData/*.ts',
                'Scripts/UnitTests/*.spec.ts' 
            ],

            exclude: [
                'Scripts/**/NodeJSDataSocket.ts'
            ],
            reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],

            //reporters: ["dots", "karma-typescript"],

            browsers: ["Chrome"],
            karmaTypescriptConfig: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    "module": "commonjs",
                    "sourceMap": true,
                    "target": "es5"
"moduleResolution": "classic",
"noImplicitAny": false
                },
                tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
            },
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like it is coming from the `extends` function TypeScript injects when you inherit from a super class.

Looking at the code, I'd say your `DataListener` is not available to you when you use it:

```
extends DataListener
```

It is probably not missing entirely, otherwise the compiler would warn you - so it is either not included (i.e. loaded) when Jasmine runs, or you've got things loading out of order.

Get them in order and hopefully... joy!

```
        files: [
            'Scripts/DeviceData/DataListener.ts',
            'Scripts/DeviceData/ConsoleListener.ts',
            'Scripts/UnitTests/*.spec.ts' 
        ],
```

Comment: Excellent - this seems obvious in retrospect. My first thought was that it wasn't included in the karma.config, but it should be - I've posted that above. Any other ideas on why it wouldn't be included? In the meantime, I've got a standalone file I can isolate and test to confirm this.

Comment: Yep, that worked, so it's definitely the inheritance there.

Comment: Which file is `DataListener` in?

Comment: It is in the same directory as ConsoleListener, i.e., Scripts/DeviceData.

Comment: Aha! So they are loading (probably) alphabetically, `ConsoleListener` is loading before `DeviceData`, so although you load both scripts, you actually need to enforce the ordering to ensure the class you depend on is first.

Answer (score 2):

The [`__extends()` function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes-emit.html#extends) is generated by the TypeScript compiler to handle class inheritance. `b` means base class and `d` is for derived class. So, the issue is that the base class `DataListener` is missing. Check the way your compiling and bundling the scripts. One namespace (cf. `module` keyword) can be defined across several files but their gathering/bundling must be handled by hand or with the [compiler option `--outFile`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).